# Стоит ли работать со структурой, содержащей внутри себя другие структуры, если потом работать с этой структурой через двусвязный список?

Tags: c++, двусвязный-список

Получил задание по курсовой - реализовать на С++ динамическую структуру, которая содержит информацию: факультет, группа, число студентов, число стипендий, средний балл группы, фамилия старосты через двусвязные списки.

Сейчас хочу выбрать, как стоит представить узел списка - как структуру, содержащую все эти поля, т.е. представляющую собой отдельную группу (назову ее простой) или же как структуру, которая содержит в себе поле названия факультета и вложенную структуру с группами, которая в свою очередь уже содержит поля относящиеся к группе(назовем ее сложной).

Поскольку не знаком с тонкостями реализации двусвязных списков (без использования классов и STL, так как предмет - не ООП, т.е. делать все вручную), мне хотелось бы понимать, насколько сложнее будет реализовать задачу с узлом, представляющим собой сложную структуру. Сложный вариант мне нравится больше, но из-за недостатка опыта, опасаюсь, что не хватит знаний его реализовать и я просто потеряю время. Подскажите, как лучше сделать, и если есть возможность, подкиньте материалов о том, как реализовывать двусвязный список (не в общем случае, где данные представляют собой инты, а в подобном моему), и как делать это со "сложной" структурой.

Comment: Кроме того, использование конструкторов, деструкторов и всего, что связано с классами не приветствуется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А это точно C++? 
Если нельзя использовать конструкторы, деструкторы, операторы, то проще писать на Си наверное. Там как раз будут только структуры.

Про двусвязные списки - вместо `int` используете указатели на ваши структуры, вам нужно разобраться как выделять память под структуры, как освобождать эту память, и всё (`new/delete` плюсовые или `malloc/free` сишные).

Дальше просто плодите структуры под ваши сущности, и пишите функции которые их создают, заполняют, удаляют и т.п.

Судя по заданию от Вас требуется сделать список групп, то есть одна структура описывает группу (`простая` Вашими словами), другая(ие) структуры требуются для создания двусвязного списка из этих структур.

Пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int a;
    char* text;
}data;


data* create_data(int a, const char* text){
    data* ret = malloc(sizeof(data));
    ret->a = a;
    size_t text_len = strlen(text);
    ret->text = malloc(sizeof(char) * (text_len + 1));
    ret->text = strcpy(ret->text, text);
    return ret;
}

void free_data(data* d){
    if (d->text != NULL){
        free(d->text);
        d->text = NULL;
    }
}


typedef struct node{
    data* d;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev;
}node;

node* create_node(data* d){
    node* ret = malloc(sizeof(node));
    ret->next = NULL;
    ret->prev = NULL;
    ret->d = d;
    return ret;
}

void free_node(node* n){
    if (n->d != NULL){
        free_data(n->d);
        free(n->d);
        n->d = NULL;
    }
}


typedef struct{
    node* head;
    node* tail;
}linked_list;

linked_list* create_list(){
    linked_list* ret = malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
    ret->head = NULL;
    ret->tail = NULL;
    return ret;
}

void free_list(linked_list* l){
    node* cur = l->head;
    while (cur != NULL){
        free_node(cur);
        cur = cur->next;
        if (cur != NULL){
            if (cur->prev != NULL)
                free(cur->prev);
        }
    }
}

linked_list* add_to_tail(linked_list* l, data* d){
    node* new_node = create_node(d);
    new_node->next = NULL;
    new_node->prev = l->tail;
    if (l->tail == NULL){
        l->tail = new_node;
        l->head = new_node;
    }else{
        l->tail->next = new_node;
        l->tail = new_node;
    }
    return l;
}

void print_list(linked_list* l){
    node* cur = l->head;
    while (cur != NULL){
        printf("node a:%d text:%s\n", cur->d->a, cur->d->text);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    linked_list* list = create_list();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        list = add_to_tail(list, create_data(i, "hello"));
    }
    print_list(list);
    free_list(list);
    free(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
node a:0 text:hello
node a:1 text:hello
node a:2 text:hello
node a:3 text:hello
node a:4 text:hello
node a:5 text:hello
node a:6 text:hello
node a:7 text:hello
node a:8 text:hello
node a:9 text:hello
```